# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in matrix multiplication

Tags: java, matrix

I'm multiplying  `Matrix1[10][2] * Matrix2[2][20]` but every time my class tries to multiplies , always throws me the same exception as the mentioned title. But when i put in rows less than the number in columns on matrix 1 and  columns less than  number on rows on matrix two, it performs the matrix multiplication without problem  this is my class for Multiplication

```
public class MatrixCompute extends RecursiveAction 
{ 

    private CreateMatrix a,b;
    private  CreateMatrix c;
    private int row; 


    MatrixCompute(CreateMatrix a , CreateMatrix b ,CreateMatrix c )
    {       
        this(a , b ,c,-1);
    }
    MatrixCompute(CreateMatrix a, CreateMatrix b, CreateMatrix c, int row)
    {
            if (a.getCols() != b.getRow()) 
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("rows/columns mismatch");
            }
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
            this.row = row;
    }   

    @Override
    public void compute() 
    {
        if (row == -1)
        {
         List<MatrixCompute> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
         for (int row = 0; row < a.getRow(); row++)
         {
                    tasks.add(new MatrixCompute(a, b, c, row));
         }
         invokeAll(tasks);
       } 
       else
       {
          multiplyRowByColumn(a, b, c, row);
       }
    }

        void multiplyRowByColumn(CreateMatrix a, CreateMatrix b, CreateMatrix c, int row) {
             for (int j = 0; j < b.getCols(); j++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < a.getCols(); k++) {
                        c.setValue(row, j, (int)(c.getValue(row, j) +  a.getValue(row, k)* b.getValue(k, j)));
                    }
                }
        }

}
```

and the class for wrapping a matrix:

```
public class CreateMatrix 
{
    private int[][] matrix; 


    public CreateMatrix (int row, int col )
    {
        matrix = new int[row][col]; 
    }

    public void fillMatrix()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length ;j++ )
            {
                 Random r = new Random();
                matrix[i][j] = r.nextInt() * 5;
            }   
        }

    }



    public int getCols()
    {
        return matrix[0].length;
    }
    public int getRow()
    {
       return matrix.length;
    }


     int getValue(int row, int col)
     {
            return matrix[row][col];
     }

    void setValue(int row, int col, int value)
    {
            matrix[row][col] = value;
     }
}
```

here is the statment where the operation is being executed :

```
 result = new CreateMatrix(row, col);
                     ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
                     pool.invoke(new MatrixCompute(container[0], container[1], result));
```

and  here where the matrix are being decalred:

```
CreateMatrix matrix1 =  new CreateMatrix(Integer.parseInt(txtfil.getText()), Integer.parseInt(txtcol.getText()));
                            container[0] = matrix1;
                            container[0].fillMatrix();

                            CreateMatrix matrix2 =  new CreateMatrix(Integer.parseInt(txrow.getText()), Integer.parseInt(txtcol2.getText()));
                            container[1] = matrix2;
```

an finally the size of matrix result is declared by `txrow.getText()` and `txtcol.getText()`

so since the only exception on multiplying matrix must be the columns on matrix one must be the same as row in Matrix2, so why is throwing me exception with greatest values in Matrix1's rows and Matrix2's colums

Comment: what are you actually doing with this in your MatrixCompute class's constructor     MatrixCompute(CreateMatrix a , CreateMatrix b ,CreateMatrix c )
    {       
        this(a , b ,c,-1);
    }

Comment: it's just a flag for starting iterate over the rows of the matrix ,so when rows is equal to  -1  starts iterating  over the matrix to get the  row's index of every  matrix

Comment: Post exception.

Comment: post exception ? what does that mean?

Comment: When Java encounters an exception, it prints the exception to the terminal, along with the file and line number where it happened. This is more important in debugging exceptions than posting your entire source code.

Answer (score 1):

First, a bit of Math. We know that A<sub>n,m</sub> * B<sub>m,p</sub> = C<sub>n,p</sub>. Which means that for each cell in the row i column j in C, we have:

[image: Cell Value]

So to get C we have to:

```java
int[][] matrixA = new int[n][m];
int[][] matrixB = new int[m][p];

//You could check if the matrixes above can multiply, by throwing an 
//exception if it does not.

int[][] matrixC = new int[n][p];

for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) {
    for ( int j = 0 ; j < p ; j++ ) {
        for ( int k = 0 ; k < m ; k++ ) {
            matrixC[i][j] += matrixA[i][k]*matrixB[k][j];
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: The reason your code throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception, it's because you are trying iterate beside the bounds of an array, which means you are trying to access, per example, in a Matrix1[10][2] you are trying to read the value on Matrix1[11][3], which it does not exist.

You code is a bit confusing, so I just put a bit of math to help you understand a better, cleaner and simpler way.

I hope I have helped.

Have a nice day.

Comment: This question seems less about multiplying matrices and more about handling exceptions. Your code may be fine, but if the OP runs into another ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while working with it, he's back to the same question he started with.

Comment: That exception is thrown when he tries to iterate beside the bounds of an array. Since his code is confusing I would say that it's because of its algorithm implementation. I just simplified it with a bit of math.

Comment: That's good. Now maybe you should edit that into your answer? I have a feeling the OP doesn't quite understand the concept of an exception yet, basing off this line: "so since the only exception on multiplying matrix must be the columns on matrix one must be the same as row in Matrix2..."